# Why is the 'head' in a linked list set to none?

Tags: python, singly-linked-list

hi I been trying to teach myself about data structures, and started off with reading stuff about linked lists. Im still new to python in general, but I knew the basics of classes and the syntax and all that, so decided why not just try learning this. Anyways, I got up to this part where I create a linked list class, and I know that the 'head' part of a linked list will be the first node, but not too sure as to why it is set to 'None'. Apologies if this is a dumb question :/

Here is the code to it...

```
class Node:
  def __init__(self, data): 
    self.data = data
    self.next = None

class LinkedList:
  def __init__(self):  
    self.head = None  #why is this part set to none?
```

Comment: Without setting it to something an additional check if the instance variable "head" exists at all would be necessary. "None" is the natural choice if there is no head node.

Comment: Because the `LinkedList` is initialized empty (like calling `list()`). The `__init__` doesn't allow for some initial data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's just intialization part, when linkedlist is intialise you dont expect it to have vaules.

```
ll = LinkedList()
node = Node(1)
ll.head = node
```

this will make node as the head of the linked list and you can add the values to it later

Answer (score 0):

When you create the object of the class LinkedList like `ll = LinkedList()`, it by default calls the constructor of the class i.e. **init**().

Obviously when you create the object but haven't assigned it to any node, it is a empty linked list and we show an empty linked list like a pointer head that is pointing to none because the list is empty.

I hope this clarifies your question.